# a funtion can not return right value

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion, return

I am defining a function for seeking recursively for a file, BUT it's weird that it can't return the path to the file.

At first, I define a function

```
import os
def searchFile(target,root):
    items = os.listdir(root)
    for item in items:
        path = os.path.join(root,item)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            #print(path)
            searchFile(target,path)
        elif os.path.isfile(path):
            #print(path)
            if os.path.basename(path) == target:
                print('if have already executed!!! ')
                print(path)
                print(target)
                return path
```

The function behaves as follows

Case 1:

When I use this function to find file_1 in the current path ".", the function return the full path to the file_1

```
return_value = searchFile(target='file_1',root='.')
print(return_value)   #  ./file_1
```

Case 2:

When I use this function to find file_1 in the directory "./result_new" for instance, the function returns "None"

```
return_value = searchFile(target = 'file_1',root='.')
print(return_value) # None
```

I expect this function should return the path to the file.

Comment: Store output of this call "searchFile(target, path)" based on value return the path

Comment: Sorry,I can't understand

Comment: Check out the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing First **If Block** :

```
   if os.path.isdir(path):
        #print(path)
        path_file = searchFile(target,path)
        if path_file is not None:
            return path_file
```

**Note** : it's because you are not handling the output of multi-level recursive calls.

Code Link: https://ideone.com/D2LlEr

**Note-1**: it will return path of the first file found.